# UILabel inside Stack View

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I am trying to have a `Stack View` which contains 3 `UILabels`. The problem is that even after setting the compression resistance priorities, I still get warnings. Updating the frames doesn't work no matter what I do. I guess it has to do with the fact that the labels have intrinsic size? How should I resolve these warnings? Thanks!

[image][image: [2]][image]

Comment: Have you updated the frames after setting the constraints?

Comment: @fiks I already mentioned i tried updating the frames, but nothing will happen. The warnings remain.

Comment: If you can explicitly constrain the labels' heights (i.e. unchanging text), adding a height constraint for at least one label should silence all three layout warnings

Comment: It's bug in Interface Builder. Everything is fine when running on device. Make sure you have different compression resistance and content hugging set for all elements in Stack View to avoid impossible to resolve constraints. AFAIK this has been fixed in Xcode 8.

Comment: Thanks @Andy! After installing Xcode 8 the warnings disappeared!

Answer (score 0):

Please, remove height constraint from stackview. That will solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by height constraint? I only have those 4 constraints for the stack view.

Comment: Remove bottom constraint from stackview. For your design you shared, your stack view should have only 3 constraints, Leading, trailing and Top.

Comment: I don't see why that matters. Even if i remove it, the warnings remain. As @Andy mentioned, installing Xcode 8 did the trick.

Comment: Why only 3? Normally you would have 4

Comment: This is what UIStackView is. Vertical stack view dynamically increase its height depending on the its subviews. Same for horizontal stack views width. There are certain cases where you need to set bottom constraint, but not in your case.
Please download following series on UIStackView  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BydbaJgkF0znTjVTcFBBT0VOTGc/view)